# Is there a way to convert a .csv format embedded in a website to an actual csv to use read.csv() on?

Tags: r, rstudio

Basically, on baseball-reference.com there is a way to switch the tables to csv format, but not actually a .csv link. I am trying to see if the csv formatted text on the webpage can be converted to a .csv file in order to make it a usable table.

I tried to use the normal 'rvest' package with the following code

```
#Los Angeles Dodgers
dodgerBatting <- read_html('https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/LAD/2019.shtml')
dodgerCSV <- dodgerBatting%>%
  html_nodes('#csv_team_batting')%>%
  html_text()
print(head(dodgerCSV))
```

The results are basically an empty character
`character(0)`

Comment: The short answer is no, if you want to scrape this site then you'll have to parse whatever HTML is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the tables present on the webpage using `html_table` command in `rvest`.

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/LAD/2019.shtml"

out_table <- url %>% read_html %>%  html_table()
```

This returns a list of dataframes, we can access individual dataframes using `out_table[[1]]`, `out_table[[2]]`. You might need to do some cleaning before using them.

If needed in csv format, we can use `write.csv` command to write them

```
write.csv(out_table[[1]], "/path/of/the/file.csv")
```